# Ever have any trouble with allowing the WinEventLog:Security to be huge?

Tags: windows, event-log

Currently my WinEventLog:Security is set to 128MB max, at which point it writes over old events.  I would like to make this log much larger, hopefully a few Gigs.  Besides the longer search time if I were to manually parse through the event log, are they any other ill effects I could expect when making such a change?